# Fixed and overlayed position in CSS

Tags: html, css

How do you get a div position fixed where it also doesn't overlay on top of another div?

For example:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="background-color:black; height:200px;">
</div>
<div style="background-color:blue; height:400px;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is for the top div to always be at the top but not to block any part of the bottom div. For an example: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

The black menu at the top always stays at the top while not obscuring the view of any other div. I examined the topbar css on that website and plugged it into my own test document but I can't get the desired effect. What else do I need to do besides "position:fixed;"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top bar in your example does start obscuring things once you start scrolling. However, in your case, I think you should just add a padding to the top of your `body` equal to the height of your black bar. That way, everything is pushed down and it won't cover anything else up.

Comment: correct. in the posted link `header .inner` has a 45px top padding.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of how it could be done

http://jsfiddle.net/fk3wY/3/

So basicly:

```
body {
   padding-top:40px;
}
#top {
   position:fixed;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   height:40px;
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Both answers are good, but I'm giving him the check because he posted first. Still voted you up, though.